# Store "9999999.00000000" in SQL Server 2008 R2: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to store `9999999.00000000` in SQL Server 2008 R2. But, I was repeatedly facing this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Database column is of type `DECIMAL(15,8)`

Please advise me, how to solve it..

C# Code:

```
  loSqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RUN", loOPERATION_TYPE.RUN.handleDBNull()));

  xxxx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SPNAME".getSql(loSqlParameters), loSqlParameters.Cast<object>().ToArray())
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME]  
     @RUN AS DECIMAL(15,8)
 AS    
 BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO TABLENAME (RUN) VALUES  (@RUN)
 END
```

Table schema:

```
Column Name     Data Type       Allow Nulls
RUN             decimal(15,8)    yes
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I think, it doesn't count..  Please try this in SQL SERVER SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,8),9999999)

Comment: Looks like some other value is being rejected. Please can you post some more code showing how you obtain and use the value in question?

Comment: @Neil Moss: now you can advice, how to solved it. if you need any other detail, please let me know..

Comment: Works just fine in T-SQL for SQL Server 2012 ... I don't see how and where you're setting up the `SqlParameter` in your C# code.....

Comment: I think you should put a watch on the values coming out of 
loSqlParameters - I expect one of them to be out of range. 

Execute the 'loSqlParameters.Cast<object>().ToArray()' 
expression in its own operation and save the result to a 
variable. Put a watch on that variable, or you could use 
conditional breakpoints to break only if the value 
is >= 10000000 or <= -10000000

Answer (score 1):

This works correctly in SQL2008R2 when executed in SSMS. If you run SQL Profiler and capture the SQL text being submitted by your application, you can check the stored procedure call including the parameter(s) being passed to the procedure. It is possible that the parameter value being sent is not what you are expecting to be sent.

My SQL test code:

```
    CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (
      Run decimal(15, 8) NULL
    );
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spName
        @Run AS DECIMAL(15,8)
    AS    
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO MyTable(Run) VALUES(@Run)
    END;
    GO

    EXEC dbo.spName 9999999.00000000;
    GO

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable;
```